# How to set a maximum number of columns in a Compose LazyVerticalGrid?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I create a `LazyVerticalGrid` I can set the minSize of the columns with this:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 192.dp),
```

The problem is that I want to specify that max number of columns must be 2, but I can't find any parameter to do it.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GridCells.Fixed` instead of `GridCells.Adaptive`.

So the working code will be

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(count = 2),
...
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do it, you have to derive number of columns from the width of the `LazyVerticalGrid`, something like:

```
val colWidth = 192.dp
val density = LocalDensity.current
var gridWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
val gridColumns by remember {
    derivedStateOf { if (gridWidth > colWidth * 2) 2 else 1 }
}
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(gridColumns),
    modifier = Modifier
        .onPlaced { gridWidth = with(density) { it.size.width.toDp() } }
) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide `LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp` by the width you want. then use ceil and minOf to set the number of columns up to 2.

```
val screenWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp // current screen width
val maxColumns = 2
val numOfColumns by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        minOf(ceil(screenWidth / 192.dp).toInt(), maxColumns)
    }
}

LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(numOfColumns)) {
    // content
}
```